# Send a notification to the iPhone while connected to an Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to make a button on the Apple Watch that, when tapped, will send a notification to the iPhone making it beeping and turning on his screen. Trouble is that, when iPhone is paired to an Apple Watch, all notifications plays on the Apple Watch. Is there a way to send a notification exclusively to iPhone?

Edit: Technically should be possible, this app do that! https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/lookout-free/id434893913?mt=8

Comment: Isn't this just the "ping phone" button that is already on the watch?

Comment: Yes but I want to replicate and expand that

Comment: I don't believe that you can control notification routing programatically. If the user turns off notifications for your app in the Watch App on their phone then it should prevent notifications from being delivered to the watch

Comment: Yes, normally it's so, but maybe in new WhatchConnectivity framework there's something hidden that someone has discovered...

Comment: With WatchConnectivity, you can send messages back and forth between the iOS app and the WatchKit app. I believe you can send a message in the background to the iOS app from the Watch, after which point you can maybe fire off a local push notification.